# Using properties inside a Javascript object literal

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create javascript json object that has a dynamic field that will just return a value based on previously specified properties. So far This is what I have...

```
var car = {
  color: 'red',
  wheels: 4,
  hubcaps: 'spinning',
  age: 4,
  full_name: this.color + ' ' + this.spinning
}
```

I was wondering if this is possible to do? My goal is to be able to reference values such as `car.color` or `car.full_name`. For this example car.full_name would return the value `red spinning`

Comment: That's not a "JSON object", that's an object written in object literal notation. These are not the same; JSON is a string-formatted data format that evaluates as objects and arrays. Note that JSON does not allow functions as parameters, either.

Comment: Sure, use `full_name: function () { return this.color + ' ' + this.spinning; };`. And use it like `car.full_name()`

Comment: btw. function === dynamic field that will just return a value based on previously specified properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your object in a function so you can perform operations on it, e.g. concatenations.

```
var car = function () {
    var color     = 'red',
        hubcaps   = 'spinning',
        full_name = color + ' ' + hubcaps;

    return {
       color: color,
       wheels: 4,
       hubcaps: hubcaps,
       age: 4,
       full_name: full_name
    };
// (); <- calls the anonymous function after defining it
}();

// true
car.full_name === "red spinning";
```

**Edit:** Like what @Jimmyt1988 said, if you want to instantiate new versions of this functions, i.e. OO Javascript, you can remove the inline function call `();` and use it like so

```
var myCar = new car();

alert(mycar.color);
```

Comment: This technique is a great step in the right direction. If you remove the static typing "()" at the end, you can actually instantiate new versions of this object... I'd say this is the most useful answer. var myCar = new car(); alert( myCar.color );

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 yeah i agree, but i think he just wants the array object so i did it so he wouldn't have to call the function first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot refer to other fields in the javascript literal when it is statically declared like you are doing because in the eyes of the parser, the object does not yet exist (it hasn't finished parsing) and it also doesn't set the `this` ptr like you are trying to use either.

Instead, you would have to do this:

```
var car = {
  color: 'red',
  wheels: 4,
  hubcaps: 'spinning',
  age: 4,
}

car.full_name = car.color + ' ' + car.spinning;
```

Your other option would be to turn `full_name` into either a function or a getter so that it is computed dynamically based on the other field values.

If you want `full_name` to always be dynamic, then you probably want to use a `getter` which can have a function behind it, but can be used like a property.